# How do I properly implement `operator/`?

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading

***MAJOR EDIT:*** Can someone please explain to me how to fix operator/ so that it will work properly? i realize that the shift is not always correct, such as for `10 / 3`, which will cause infinite loops. so how do i fix that?

the entire code is at http://ideone.com/GhF0e

```
uint128_t operator/(uint128_t rhs){
    // Save some calculations ///////////////////////
    if (rhs == 0){
        std::cout << "Error: division or modulus by zero" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rhs == 1)
        return *this;
    if (*this == rhs)
        return uint128_t(1);
    if ((*this == 0) | (*this < rhs))
        return uint128_t(0, 0);
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////
    uint128_t copyn(*this), quotient = 0;
    while (copyn >= rhs){
        uint128_t copyd(rhs), temp(1);
        // shift the divosr to match the highest bit
        while (copyn > (copyd << 1)){
            copyd <<= 1;
            temp <<= 1;
        }
        copyn -= copyd;
        quotient += temp;
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

is this correct?

```
    uint128_t operator/(uint128_t rhs){
        // Save some calculations ///////////////////////
        if (rhs == 0){
            std::cout << "Error: division or modulus by zero" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        if (rhs == 1)
            return *this;
        if (*this == rhs)
            return uint128_t(1);
        if ((*this == 0) | (*this < rhs))
            return uint128_t(0);
        uint128_t copyd(rhs);
        // Checks for divisors that are powers of two
        uint8_t s = 0;
        while ((copyd.LOWER & 1) == 0){
            copyd >>= 1;
            s++;
        }
        if (copyd == 1)
            return *this >> s;
        // //////////////////////////////////////////////

        uint128_t copyn(*this), quotient = 0;
        copyd = rhs;
        uint8_t n_b = 255, d_b = 0;
        while (copyd){
            copyd >>= 1;
            d_b++;// bit size of denomiator
        }
        copyd = rhs;
        while (n_b > d_b){
            // get the highest bit of dividend at current step
            n_b = 0;
            uint128_t copycopyn(copyn);
            while (copycopyn){
                copycopyn >>= 1;
                n_b++;
            }
            uint8_t highest_bit = n_b - d_b - 1;
            copyn -= copyd << highest_bit;
            quotient += uint128_t(1) << highest_bit;
        }
        if (n_b == d_b)
            quotient++;
        return quotient;
    }
```

it seems to be correct, except im somehow getting random large values when modding by 10, even though my mod function is just

```
    uint128_t operator%(uint128_t rhs){
        return *this - (rhs * (*this / rhs));
    }
```

Comment: when happens when you step through the code?

Comment: What is the output you are getting. Have you tried `flush()`ing the output ?

Comment: it freezes up. i cant find the exact source of the problem, although it seems to be in the `operator/`. but like i said, as slow as it might be, it cant be //that// slow

Comment: A timeout sounds more like some infinite loop / recursion.

Comment: What infinite loop? it can display small numbers easily

Comment: @calcrypto: the infinite loop you mention in your post "is freezing up when i try to display a large number?" !!

Comment: Is this your own implementation of `uint128_t`, as in a previous question you asked? How is operator /= implemented?

Comment: @calccrypto - when running the program it consumes one of my cores. The loop it is stuck in is the `shift the divosr to match the highest bit` while loop.

Comment: It's an infinite loop.  Look at the "while (copyn > (copyd << 1))" loop in the division operator.

Comment: Where do  you get `uint128_t` type from?

Comment: Calccrypto, how did you conclude that the thing that's wrong is the `<<` operator and not anything from the 568 lines of code that preceded it? This kind of code lends itself perfectly to *unit testing*. Test each of your class's operators by itself, and once you're confident that they all work, *then* test your `<<` operator that combines the use of several other operators.

Comment: @DSM: care to tell me how to fix it?

Comment: effort???? have you noticed the 500 lines of code? ive been modifying my code for hours because something or another keeps on not working. i came here for help, not commentary. its not like im flat out asking for a full program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression "copyn > (copyd << 1)", "copyd << 1" can overflow, leading to the infinite loop you're observing.  I would suggest checking for the overflow, or making the check something more like "(copyn >> n) > copyd".

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
int div;  // Uninitialized variable.
```

What happens if all the test on the stream fail.
Then div could have any value. If it is 0 (or 1) then rhs will never reach 0.

Comment: That's definitely bad coding, but in this case I think div does get set to 10.

Answer (score 0):

If there were an infinite loop, you wouldn't even be able to output -1.  -1 isn't as small as -123455, but you should try it.  There is nothing wrong with operator << but there is something wrong with your assumption about operator /.  There's something else wrong too, but I'm not sure if I should do your homework ^_^

Comment: There's an error in the implementation of the / operator, as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it looks like:

```
stream << out;
return stream;
```

Is outside of the function, at class scope.

You probably want to get rid of one of the `}`s after `else`.